# touch 7" rpi display does not wake up when in console after rpi display goes blank

Tags: display, touchscreen

I am running Pihole+PADD on my Rpi with Raspberry 7 inch touch display on a continous basis.

For power and screen save reason I have activated blank screen after 300 seconds through raspi-config, however i cannot wake it up when touching the screen, that works perfectly when in desktop mode, but not there.

Any idea to send a keyboard stroke on such mode when using touch display, so i can avoid to have a keyboard plugged on usb port to wake up screen ?

Comment: The RPi display is NOT plug'n'play. Whenever you want to change its configuration or anything to do with the RPi display you must shutdown, pull power and re-connect power to your Raspberry to get the firmware to recognise the touch screen and enable the device.

Comment: Pi and Display are working fine for days, and display is properly working when using Desktop Pi. my only question is to have the touch part waking up a blank rpi when only using console. If i configure rpi display to goes blank after 300 seconds, it works, but only a keyboard stroke will wake it up, not a touch on the display, that's my question.